# What is the equivalent of document.getElementById("root").appendChild(node) in React?

Tags: javascript, reactjs

How do I get this functionality using React?

```js
function myFunction() {
  var node = document.createElement("div");
  var textnode = document.createTextNode("Button was clicked.");
  node.appendChild(textnode);
  document.getElementById("root").appendChild(node);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

in your render function write the div you want and make a state 
then change a state to true to the div to be shown

somthing like this

```
   constructor(props) {
        super(props)
        this.state = {
            showDiv: false
        }
    }
   render (){
       return (
            {
                this.state.showDiv ? your div : <React.Fragment />
            }
       )
   }

   changeDivDisplay(){
      this.setState({showDiv:true})
   }
```

also i do recommend you to read about the state and the refs of react